# how to get url endpoint openid provider

Tags: openid, openid-provider

how to get end point url of a openid provider like  for google if we get from https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id or for yahoo it is http://me.yahoo.com  .Similarly , for others how to find this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the web site in question and look through their docs.  There's no authoritative or complete list of OP Identifiers.

Comment: so in order to discover open id provider end point url i have to find end point url and store in databse or use if and else .

Comment: I don't know why you'd use if/else here.  Typically you don't store this information at all and let the user type it in.  If you want to offer buttons to the user to make it easier, you can just write the HTML for the buttons that include these OP Identifiers.  I've never heard of a reason to include them in a database -- unless perhaps it was a data-driven security filter to only let in only approved OP endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

U can have something like this in a js file..
`var defaultProviders = {
                    google: {
                        name: 'Google',
                        url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id',
                        hasLargeIcon: true
                    },
                    yahoo: {
                        name: 'Yahoo',
                        url: 'http://me.yahoo.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: true
                    },
                    aol: {
                        name: 'AOL',
                        label: 'Enter your AOL screenname:',
                        url: 'http://openid.aol.com/{username}',
                        hasLargeIcon: true
                    },
                    myopenid: {
                        name: 'MyOpenID',
                        label: 'Enter your MyOpenID username:',
                        url: 'http://{username}.myopenid.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: true
                    },
                    openid: {
                        name: 'OpenID',
                        url: 'http://',
                        hasLargeIcon: true
                    },
                    livejournal: {
                        name: 'LiveJournal',
                        label: 'Enter your Livejournal username:',
                        url: 'http://{username}.livejournal.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    },
                    wordpress: {
                        name: 'Wordpress',
                        label: 'Enter your Wordpress.com username:',
                        url: 'http://{username}.wordpress.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    },
                    blogger: {
                        name: 'Blogger',
                        label: 'Enter your Blogger account:',
                        url: 'http://{username}.blogspot.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    },
                    verisign: {
                        name: 'Verisign',
                        label: 'Enter your Verisign username:',
                        url: 'http://{username}.pip.verisignlabs.com/',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    },
                    claimid: {
                        name: 'ClaimID',
                        label: 'Enter your ClaimID username:',
                        url: 'http://openid.claimid.com/{username}',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    },
                    clickpass: {
                        name: 'ClickPass',
                        label: 'Enter your ClickPass username:',
                        url: 'http://clickpass.com/public/{username}',
                        hasLargeIcon: false
                    }
            };`

Than once `username` is available u can use following code to create complete URL...
`function (event) {
                    var cancel = true;
                    var val = $('input[type=text]', username).val();
                    if (val.length > 0) {
                        var pvd = providers[selectedId];
                        if (pvd) {
                            _setLoading(true, true);
                             var url = pvd.url.replace('{username}', val);
                            _setOpenIdUrl(url);
                            _setCookie(selectedId);
                              alert("URL is  : "+url);
                                   input.get()[0].form.submit();
                        }
                    }
                    if (cancel) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                };'
That will work most of the time....